# preprocess function not running on theme drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, twig

I am trying to query my database and return a number to store in a twig template called **node--course.html.twig**

So I started by writing the function *completionCheck()* in class **FormaRegis.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\docebo_login;

use Drupal\docebo_login\FormaEntity;


class FormaRegis extends FormaEntity {

     public $ID;

  public function setID($ID) {
    $this->ID = $ID;
  }

  public function getID() {
    return $this->ID;
  }

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }


 public function rowBase() {


     if (parent::accessCheck()) {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM learning_courseuser
                  WHERE idUser = " . $_SESSION['public_area_idst'] .
                 " AND idCourse = " . $this->ID. " ";
        return $sql;
       } else {

            return "";
       }

    }

    public function completionCheck() {
        $check = false;

         if (parent::accessCheck()) {
            $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM learning_courseuser
                    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%d/%m/%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(date_complete,'%d/%m/%Y')
                    AND idUser =  " . $_SESSION['public_area_idst'];

            return $sql;
          }
          else {
            return "";
          }

    }

}
```

and in a page called **FormaEntity.php** I wrote this function

```
public function getCCresult() {
   if ($this->completionCheck() == "") {
      \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection();
      return false;
   }

   $result = $this->connection->query($this->completionCheck())->fetch();
     \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection();

   if ($result > 5 ) {
     $check = "fail";
   }
   else {
     $check = "pass";
   }

   return $check;
}
```

Then in **FormaNotification.php** I wrote function *completionCheck()*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\docebo_login;

use Drupal\docebo_login\FormaEntity;

class FormaNotification extends FormaEntity {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getResult() {

         return parent::accessCheck();
    }

    public function completionCheck() {

         return parent::getCCresult();
    }

}
```

Then finally, in my .theme file I added the function *mytheme_preprocess_node_course(&$variables)*

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node_course (&$variables) {

  $noti = new FormaNotification();

  if ($noti->completionCheck() == "fail") {
      $variables['creditCheck'] = "yes";
  }
  else {
    $variables['creditCheck'] = "no";
  }

}
```

But when I visit the any page that uses the node--course.html.twig and use 
*{{ kint(creditCheck) }}*, it says that the variable in NULL. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Is your theme called mytheme?

Comment: Is the module enabled? did you kint or dump your module variables?

Comment: @Don'tPanic its not i changed it but the function matches my theme.

Comment: @danielarend the hero returns!  I'm not sure how I can check if the module is enabled or not.

Comment: go to cms ->extend and check if your module is enabled. If you have drush, you can   run drush en 'your_module'

Comment: @danielarend but I am pretty sure it is enabled since other functions work from these pages

Comment: @danielarend it is indeed enabled

Comment: Ah, okay. Sorry, I know it's kind of a silly thing, but I've accidentally done it before myself, so thought I'd ask

Comment: @Don'tPanic not silly at all! I didn not know that was a thing until yesterday. SUPER new to drupal.

Comment: I just tried to add a print "HERE I AM" followed by an exit; in my txhs_preprocess_node_course and it is not showing anywhere in the twig template so I am guessing it is being missed entirely. I have no idea why.

Comment: Well, good luck to you! I started with Drupal a few months ago, and as a pretty experienced PHP dev I really expected it to be a bit easier to learn than it has been. I'd recommend also searching on Drupal Answers. It's been a good resource to me as well as SO